# High quality elevation data for Europe

Tags: data-request, europe

I am looking for high quality elevation data for Europe. I am looking of around 2 meters or lower of resolution. So if anyone knows a good provider or programs (Can be payware or free) let me know

Answer (score 3):

if you prefer free resources, you could start with the sites listed on this page:

Free GIS Data – Elevation/ DEM/ DTM Data at Gisresources.com
https://gisresources.com/free-gis-data-elevation-dem-dtm-data/

There's also OpenDem.info with maps showing available high-res imagery: https://www.opendem.info/index.html

And this on OpenTopography.org: New 30m Digital Terrain Model Covering Continental Europe Now Available
https://opentopography.org/news/new-30m-digital-terrain-model-covering-continental-europe-now-available